# PXRedirectRequired inside PXLongOperation - not redirecting

Tags: acumatica

I'm sure I'm missing something minor but is there anything specific that needs to be specified in a BLC or ASPX page to allow redirection to function inside a PXLongOperation?

In my case, I am creating a customization to the CRCaseMaint screen that creates a sales order by action.

As a basis, In the OpportunityMaint the CreateSalesOrder action, the "DoCreateSalesOrder" method is called inside a long running process

```
                PXLongOperation.StartOperation(this, delegate()
                {
                    var grapph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<OpportunityMaint>();
                    grapph.Opportunity.Current = opportunity;
                    grapph.CreateOrderParams.Current = CreateOrderParams.Current;
                    grapph.DoCreateSalesOrder();
                });
```

The last step of the DoCreateSalesOrder method is a redirect over to the sales order screen

```
        throw new PXRedirectRequiredException(docgraph, "");
```

Seeing how this functionality is about 99% similar to what I'm attempting to accomplish I duplicated this functionality in my customization.

Everything is working as I'd expect (My action is called, my smart panel shows, my create sales order method calls) except if I place my equivalent of the "DoCreateSalesOrder" method inside a PXLongOperation, the redirect never occurs.

If I comment out the PXLongOperation wrapper, the method properly redirects to the sales order page as the final step.

Attaching a debugger shows that the sales order document exists and that it's hitting the redirect but that final redirect isn't occurring.

As mentioned, I'm sure this is something minor I forgot to set but has anyone ran across this and have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question on this as I knew it was something minor but might help someone else.

The PXLongOperation definition was incorrect.

I had this:

```
PXLongOperation.StartOperation(this, delegate ()
```

But seeing how this is a GraphExtension it should have been this:

```
PXLongOperation.StartOperation(Base, delegate ()
```

After the change, it's working as expected

Comment: Yes indeed, also in order to display the spinning wait widget, you have to pass the Graph as the first parameter. Passing a Graph Extension won't display the widget.